# Flutter how to filter array

Tags: flutter, dart

Please give me the solution for this.
I have json data here

```
{
"id": "61e7e10f5c5677",
"travel_map": [
    {
        "odometer": 0,
        "coords": {
            "altitude": 150.1,
            "heading": -1,
            "latitude": 28.5799048,
            "speed": -1,
            "longitude": 77.3191382
        }
    },
    {
        "odometer": 0,
        "coords": {
            "altitude": 149.8,
            "heading": 315.43,
            "latitude": 28.5799129,
            "speed": 0.01,
            "longitude": 77.3191291
        }
    }
]
}
```

I need to filter **latitude** and **longitude** from these data in array like this

```
[LatLng(28.5799048, 77.3191382), LatLng(28.5799129, 77.3191291)]
```

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12562-jsontodart-json-to-dart-

Comment: please read above article and use this plugin .

Comment: Without trying anything give me the solution? show some effort if you want to learn, do some research and visit [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var travelMapList = yourJson["travel_map"] as List? ?? [];
var latLangList = travelMapList.map((e) => LatLng(e["coords"]["latitude"] ?? 0, e["coords"]["longitude"] ?? 0));
print(latLangList);
```

This will print

```
(Instance of 'LatLng', Instance of 'LatLng')
```

Comment: It works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json to dart converter](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

if you get the response from api do like this

```
final parsedData=json.decode(response.body);
MyJsonToDartData data= new MyJsonToDartData.fromJson(parsedData);
```

now you can use the `data` as a object and access all the underlying values